# Environment injection to service inside app

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

By using Nx.
Created multiple apps, each app has its own environment with different API URL.
Nx Workspace library has some shared services which are using among all apps.
But need to pass the environment-api-url when inject the service in the component.

```
    @Component({
      standalone: true,
      imports: [
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       FormsModule,
       HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [AuthenticationService],
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

Can we pass like this

```
providers: [AuthenticationService<environment>]
```

or any other way to achieve it.

advanced appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another library called `app-config`. Then inside create an `index.ts` file (`lib/app-config/src/lib/config/index.ts`).

Inside of your index.ts export an InjectionToken.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('App Config');
```

Add this to the `Providers` of your `LoginComponent`.

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from '@YourWorkspaceName/app-config';

providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_CONFIG,
      useValue: environment,
    },
    AuthenticationService
]
```

Then inside your `AuthenticationService` inject `APP_CONFIG` to access your environment variables.

```
import { APP_CONFIG } from '@YourWorkspaceName/app-config';

    export class AuthenticationService {
     private readonly url: string = this.appConfig.authServiceUrl;
    
     constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: any
      ) {}
    
     login(EmailAddress: string, Password: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<{ authToken: string }>(`${this.url}/login`, {
          EmailAddress,
          Password,
        });
      }
    }
```

Hope you find this helpful.